# jquery traversing dom

Tags: jquery

How do I select the last div id blog_comments in this row?

```
    <div id="blog_comments">
        <div class="name"><span class="blog_bold">By: </span>SamSambinks</div>
    </div>

    <div id="blog_comments">
        <div class="name"><span class="blog_bold">By: </span>SamSambinks</div>
    </div>

    <div id="blog_comments">
        <div class="name"><span class="blog_bold">By: </span>SamSambinks</div>
    </div>
```

Sounds like a simple question I've tried:
    `$("#blog_comments:last")` and `$("#blog_comments").last`

and others but nothing seems to work?

Comment: blog_comments should be a class not an id.  Try doing $("div.blog_comments:last").

Answer (score 4):

The reason why it's not working is `id` needs to be unique.
Make them `classes` instead of creating non-unique `id's`, having duplicate `id's` is actually invalid markup.

```
<div class="blog_comments">
   <div class="name"><span class="blog_bold">By: </span>SamSambinks</div>
</div>

<div class="blog_comments">
   <div class="name"><span class="blog_bold">By: </span>SamSambinks</div>
</div>

<div class="blog_comments">
   <div class="name"><span class="blog_bold">By: </span>SamSambinks</div>
</div>
```

Then your selector:

```
$('.blog_comments').last();
```

Working Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/GxXFq/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple DOM nodes with same id. Try to change `id="blog_comments"` to `class="blog_comments"`.

Comment: For some reason $(".blog_comments").last() didn't work but $("blog_comments:last") did?